# To find solution of differential equations $ \dot{x} = x + y^{2} $ and $ \dot{y} = -y $ where initial condition $x(0)=x_{0}$ and $y(0)=y_{0}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:** Look at the differential equations.
$$
\dot{x} = x + y^{2} \\ 
\dot{y} = -y
$$
with initial conditions $x(0)=x_{0}$ and $y(0)=y_{0}$. Determine the general solution of this initial value problem.

**My attempt:**
First solve $\dot{y}=-y$. The solution is easy to see, take $y=y_{0}e^{-x}$. Now substitute $\dot{x}=x+y_{0}^{2}e^{-2x}$. Using the method of integrating factors

$r(x) = e^{\int p(x)dx} = e^{\int -dx} = e^{-x} $

$$
e^{-x} \dot{x} - e^{-x} x = e^{-x} y_{0}^{2}e^{-2x}
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx} [e^{-x}x] = e^{-x} y_{0}^{2}e^{-2x}
$$
$$
e^{-x}x= \int e^{-x} e^{-2x} y_{0}^{2} = -\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x} + C
$$
$$
x = e^{x}(-\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}+C) = -\frac{1}{3}e^{-2x}+e^{x}C
$$

I would like to know if this is correct.

Comment: I do not completely understand your attempt...I think a possible hint is the following: given any $y_0\in \R$, the solution of the second equation is $y(t)=y_0 e^{-t}$ and thus the first equation becomes $x'(t)=x(t) +y_0^2 e^{-2t}$. Now, for any $x_0 \in \R$ you can use variation of the constant formula to obtain the solution in a closed form.

Comment: Are you solving the system of ODE?

Comment: Just a try : set $\dot y=-y\implies y\dot y=-y^2$, and make the substitution $z=y^2$.

Comment: You mixed up $x_0$ and $y_0$ at the start. Also at the end you need to pin down the second constant of integration using $x_0$.

Comment: The solution to $\dot y = -y$ should involve $y_0$, not $x_0$, that is a typo. (Same comment as Ian above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is almost right, but you've mixed up the functions and the variables. $x$ and $y$ are functions, so let's call their variable something, let's say $t$, so $x=x(t), y=y(t)$. Other than that, you simply forgot to carry the $y_0^2$ term.

---

A correct solution looks like this:

Let's first solve $\dot{y} = -y, \ y(0)=y_0$. A general solution for this is $y = y_0 e^{-x}$, which you are absolutely right about.

So the first equation transforms into

$$\dot{x} = x + y_0^2 e^{-2t} \quad (*)$$

Let us try to find $x$ in the form of

$$x = fg \quad (**)$$

So

$$\dot{x} = \dot{f}g + \dot{g}f \stackrel{(*)}{=} x + y_0^2 e^{-2t}$$

Let

$$\begin{align*}
\text{I.} \quad &\dot{f}g = x \\
\text{II.} \quad &\dot{g}f = y_0^2 e^{-2t}
\end{align*}$$

Due to $\text{I.}$ and $(**)$, $\forall t$:

$$\begin{align*}
fg &= \dot{f}g \\
f &= \dot{f} \\
f &= c_1 e^{t}
\end{align*}$$

And due to $\text{II.}$:

$$\begin{align*}
\dot{g}f = y_0^2 e^{-2t} \\
\dot{g}c_1 e^{t} = y_0^2 e^{-2t} \\
\dot{g} = \frac{y_0^2}{c_1} e^{-3t} \\
g = -\frac{y_0^2}{3c_1} e^{-3t} + c_2
\end{align*}$$

So from $(**)$:

$$x = fg = c_1 e^{t} \left(-\frac{y_0^2}{3c_1} e^{-3t} + c_2\right) = -\frac{y_0^2}{3} e^{2t} + c_3 e^t$$

With the initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ you can subsitute and find that $c_3 = x_0 + \frac{y_0^2}{3}$, so the solution is

$$\boxed{\begin{align*}
x &= x(t) = -\frac{y_0^2}{3} e^{2t} + \left(x_0 + \frac{y_0^2}{3}\right) e^t \\
y &= y(t) = y_0 e^{-t}
\end{align*}}$$

---

And you can check that this is right, as

$$\dot{x} = \frac{2}{3}y_0^2 e^{-2t} + \left(x_0 + \frac{y_0^2}{3}\right) e^t = x + y_0^2 e^{-2t} = x+y^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something as : In a neighborhood were $y$ doesn't vanished ;

$$\begin{cases}\dot x=x+y^2\\ \dot y=-y\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}\dot x=x+y^2\\ y\dot y=y^2\end{cases}\underset{z=y^2}{\iff}\begin{cases}\dot x=x+z\\\dot z=2 z\end{cases}.$$

Then, you get a linear system...